# Spark job in Kubernetes stuck in RUNNING state

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I'm submitting Spark jobs in Kubernetes running locally (Docker desktop). I'm able to submit the jobs and see their final output in the screen.

However, even if they're completed, the driver and executor pods are still in a RUNNING state.

The base images used to submit the Spark jobs to kubernetes are the ones that come with Spark, as described in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html).

This is what my `spark-submit` command looks like:

```
~/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443 \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name my-spark-job \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=my-spark-job \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.submission.waitAppCompletion=false \
    local:///opt/spark/work-dir/my-spark-job.py
```

And this is what `kubectl get pods` returns:

```
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
my-spark-job-1568669908677-driver   1/1     Running   0          11m
my-spark-job-1568669908677-exec-1   1/1     Running   0          10m
my-spark-job-1568669908677-exec-2   1/1     Running   0          10m
```

Comment: What's in the pod logs? Is this specific to your job? Did you try wordcount example?

Comment: Thanks @Dagang reviewing the wordcount example I could see the isuse. I forgot to `stop` the SparkContext.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out. I forgot to `stop` the Spark Context. My script looks like this now, and at completion, the driver goes into `Completed` status and the drivers get deleted.

```
sc = SparkContext()

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

# code

sc.stop()
```