# Why spark executor are not dying

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, kubernetes, airflow

Here is my setup:

Kubernetes cluster running `airflow`, which submits the `spark` job to Kubernetes cluster, job runs fine but the container are suppose to die once the job is done but they are still hanging there.

1. Airflow Setup comes up on K8S cluster.
2. `Dag` is baked in the airflow docker image because somehow I am not able to sync the dags from `s3`. For some reason the `cron` wont run.
3. Submits the `spark` job to K8S Cluster and job runs fine.
4. But now instead of dying post execution and completion of job it still hangs around.

Here is my `SparkSubmitOperator` function

```py
spark_submit_task = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id='spark_submit_job_from_airflow',
    conn_id='k8s_spark',
    java_class='com.dom.rom.mainclass',
    application='s3a://some-bucket/jars/demo-jar-with-dependencies.jar',
    application_args=['300000'],
    total_executor_cores='8',
    executor_memory='20g',
    num_executors='9',
    name='mainclass',
    verbose=True,
    driver_memory='10g',
    conf={
        'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider': 'com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider',
        'spark.rpc.message.maxSize': '1024',
        'spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.impl': 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem',
        'spark.kubernetes.container.image': 'dockerhub/spark-image:v0.1',
        'spark.kubernetes.namespace' : 'random',
        'spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy': 'IfNotPresent',
        'spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName': 'airflow-spark'
        },
    dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you have the same problem as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964848/spark-job-in-kubernetes-stuck-in-running-state

Comment: Actually that's what exactly my issue

Comment: In this case, that answer should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured the problem it was my mistake I wasn't closing the `spark session`, added the following

```
session.stop();
```